# Flask_debugtoolbar, cannot import name '_reqeust_ctx_stack' from 'flask.globals'

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, web

when i run the code on virtual environment. this is what I get.

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_request_ctx_stack' from 'flask.globals'(../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/globals.py)
```

This keeps popping up after I upgrade packages.

Here's my code.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, flash, session
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "This is demo"
app.config['DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS'] = False
deubg = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    """Shows home page"""
    return render_template('home.html')
```

```
these are my packages on my requirement.txtblinker==1.6.3click==8.1.7Flask==3.0.0Flask-DebugToolbar==0.13.1itsdangerous==2.1.2Jinja2==3.1.2MarkupSafe==2.1.3Werkzeug==3.0.0
```

I've tried pip install flask_debugtoolbar, and I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error comes from Flask_debugtoolbar not supporting Flask version 3.0.0 yet. There is a fix for Flask_debugtoolbar in [this PR](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-debugtoolbar/pull/183), but at the time of writing is yet to be released.

For now, the way to make this work would be to pin to an older version of Flask, like v2.3.3.